# Measure CPU time usage in Matlab (in milliseconds)

Tags: matlab

How can I measure the time used by Matlab in the execution of some commands? I am looking for something like linux `time` command, which returns the actual CPU used (user + sys), instead of the total time transcurred, which can vary depending on system usage by other processes.

Also, the time should be returned in milliseconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`cputime`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cputime.html):

> **CPUTIME** CPU time in seconds.
>       CPUTIME returns the CPU time in seconds that has been used
>       by the MATLAB process since MATLAB started.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>    t=cputime; your_operation; cputime-t
> ```
>
> returns the cpu time used to run your_operation.
>
> The return value may overflow the internal representation
>       and wrap around.

There's also [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html).

And you can also use `tic`/ `toc` (see [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23663210/2586922)).

See [some useful comments](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/analyzing-your-programs-performance.html) on measuring CPU time. According to the above link, `tic` / `toc` and `timeit` give more accurate estimations than `cputime`.

Comment: I am worried about the overflow warning. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Whenever it wraps around, cputime - t will not give the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple clock time solution, use `tic` and `toc`

`profile` provides a detailed report code per line, you can choose between cpu time and real time.

Comment: From what I read, `tic` and `toc` return real time instead of cpu time. As for `profile`, I only need the cpu time, and it seems that `profile` collects a bunch of other information I don't need. Won't that impact performance?

Comment: @becko: profiler adds a significant overhead, which is not shown in the report.